# How to enable Spotlight on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight, windows-10-v1803

I have Windows 10 Education 1803 (17134.1) and I cannot select `Spotlight` from 
Settings->Lock screen->Background.

I only have `Picture` or `Slideshow`.

How can I enable Spotlight?

Comment: Are you by chance using a *Windows N* version of Windows 10 Enterprise?  If that is indeed the case.  Have you tried to install the [Media Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack)?

Comment: No just a education one without the N

Comment: There are `Cloud Content` and `Personalization` group policies that would block Spotlight from working.  Are those applicable policies enabled by chance?  [I have other questions but far to many for the comment section](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Spotlight is not available on certain Windows 10 Education versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures" registry key is enabled on your side. If it was enabled, try to disable it. If it not exist, try to create it.

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent
REG_DWORD "DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures"=0 (disable)

Answer (score 0):

The spotlight feature is not available for my Windows 10 Pro N too, maybe you could take a look at this app https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/dynamic-theme.